# Add validation to a dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, validation

In my .aspx page, I have a dropdown list.

The first value that it defaults to is 'please choose', and it has the value of -1.

How can I add validation to it so someone chooses an item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a required field Validator.  There is a default value option which you can set to the default value of the drop down.

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="-1" ControlToValidate="yourControl" runat="server" ID="rf1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

[link to msdn for more detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Change the value of 'please choose' to Value="" and try this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="req" runat="server" ControlToValidate="YourDropDownList"
            ErrorMessage="Select item" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```